# gpo implementation windows server 2012r2

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, preferences

I am looking to Configuring Windows 7 Libraries using Group Policy Preferences "Disable Known Folders". gpupdate /force is completed successfully, therefore policy is not applied to client computer?? 
Any idea why?

Comment: This is a User Configuration setting. Are you applying the GPO to users or computers?

Comment: Configuration will apply to users.

Answer (score 0):

Use with a new local user profile.

As per the GPO description; "If the folder exists before the policy is applied, the folder must be manually deleted since the policy only blocks the creation of the folder".

Comment: the folder exist a part of OS and Library folder music, videos, pictures and my documents are default. I cannot delate the folder manually, I am talking about 1000 client computers mainly using MS Win7 desktop/laptop. I already implemented a GPO to hide linked folder from start menu, hence users can access using windows explorer folder. Here I can use new GPO with "Disable Known Folders" to hide them from, BUT Policy is not being applied.

Comment: @C.Lav The GPO state the setting MUST be done before any user profile is created, else, I seen script to remove those folder from explorer, but it's not the same answer, please edit your question

Comment: See my answer to the solution implemented using GPO.

Answer (score 0):

Create GPO:
User Configuration->Preference->Windows Settings->Files
File (Target Path Source - Empty
Destination Path C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Library.Name-ms

General Tab: Action - Delete
Suppress errors on individual files - Enabled

Attributes:
Read Only -Disabled
Hidden: Disabled
Archive: Enabled

Common Tab:Apply once and do not reapply - YES, other NO

GPUPDATE / FORCE server
GPUPDATE Clients

Library is no longer available.